# Script inside shadow dom not working

Tags: javascript, angular, web-component, shadow-dom, angular-elements

I've created and exported one Angular Element (web component in Angular) as a single script tag (user-poll.js).
To use this Angular Element I just need to specify below two lines in the host site:

```
 <user-poll></user-poll>
 <script src="path/to/user-poll.js"></script>
```

[Working JSBin Example](http://jsbin.com/migegukako/edit?html,js,output)

I've following requirements:

1. Load multiple Angular Elements on the external site.
2. Load all Angular Elements dynamically

I've following issues:

1. Loading multiple components on a site gives Angular conflicts, as each component script is a complete Angular app in itself.
2. To solve conflict issue, I am loading each component in a separate **Shadow Dom** component (i.e. adding component tag and component script file link inside shadow dom container) so that each component is sandboxed. But component script inside shadow dom not working.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/jayetiqehe/edit?html,output) of the dynamically loading component inside the shadow dom

```
<body>

</body>
    setTimeout(() => {
    loadJS();
}, 2000);
function loadJS() {
    var elm = document.createElement("div");
    elm.attachShadow({mode: "open"});
    elm.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `<user-poll><h2>Custom Web Component - user-poll loaded</h2><script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/SaurabhLpRocks/795f67f8dc9652e5f119bd6060b58265/raw/d5490627b623f09c84cfecbd3d2bb8e09c743ed4/user-poll.js"><\/\script></user-poll>`;
    document.body.appendChild(elm);
}
```

So, what is the best way to dynamically load multiple Angular Elements on a site?

Comment: One thing to note is `elm.innerHTML` is not using the ShadowDOM. For that you'd want to use `elm.shadowRoot.innerHTML`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: My Bad! Corrected example to proper ShadowDOM.

Comment: also the content of the loaded script is not designed to work with shadow dom

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The fact that the script is not executed is not related to Shadow DOM, but to the way you try to insert the `<script>` element, that is via a string in `innerHTML`.
In this case the string is not interpreted and the script not executed.

If you want it to work you must insert the `<script>` via `appendChild()`.

You can do it directly by adding a `<script>` element created with `createElement()`, or by using a `<template>` element.

**1. with createElement()**

Create a `<script>` element and append it to its parent:

```js
var up = document.createElement( 'user-poll' )
var script = document.createElement( 'script' )
script.textContent = 'document.write( "executed" )'
up.appendChild( script )
elm.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
   .appendChild( up )
```

```html
<div id="elm"></div>
```

**2. with a `<template>` tag**

Append the content of a `<template>` element:

```js
elm.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
   .appendChild( tpl.content )
```

```html
<template id="tpl">
    <user-poll>
        <script>document.write( 'exected' )</script>
    </user-poll>
</template>

<div id="elm"></div>
```

The script is not executed when the `<template>` element is parsed, but when its `content` is appended to the DOM.

**PS**: anyway I'm not sure it's the best way to load multiple Angular elements: Shadow DOM won't act as a sandbox for Javascript code, as `<iframe>` does. Instead maybe you'll have to use a module loader.